# Google Rich Snippets for logo and website description

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

How can I show logo and website description as snippets in Google search result?

I tried reading on Rich Snippets but seems like there is no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do your part and correctly implement the [Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/).
2. Create a sitemap and submit it on Google Webmasters so that Google finds and crawls your pages and detect the snippets in your markup.
3. Google then will decide when to show your snippets according to several criteria described in their [Webmaster Quality Guidlines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769) and [Structured Data Policies](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies).
4. Be patient. Stuff related to SEO take time but they are eventually fruitful.

Reference: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/)

Comment: What kind of rich snippet should I implement? I have read the docs, they only show following: Product, Recipe, Review, Event, SoftwareApplication

Comment: Yes those and also videos and articles. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google’s documenation, the logo can only be shown [for organizations](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/logos) (not as Rich Snippet, but possibly in the Knowledge Graph). It makes use of Schema.org’s [`logo` property](http://schema.org/logo) (on [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization)).

It’s unclear what you mean with "website description", as Google displays a short snippet by default anyway (either taken from the page’s content, or from the `meta`-`description`).